# ETIMEDOUT error in node.js while handling multiple requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, autoscaling

I have a server written in node which uses mysql as its database and the frontend is written in react. My app is hosted on a dedicated server having cpu with 4 cores. The frontend has to load cricket odds for which I am using a third party api. The react app sends request to my node server as per matchId and then server send request to the third party api and receives odds then pass it on to the frontend. The code is as follows:

```
router.get('/getSession/:matchId',(req,res)=>{
    
    axios.get('http://178.62.105.201/api/v1/listMarketBookSession?match_id='+req.params.matchId)
            .then(response => {
               
                return res.status(200).json({
                    success:true,
                    data:response.data
                })
            })
            .catch(error=>{
                console.log(error);
                return res.status(200).json({
                    success:false,
                    data:[]
                })
            });
})
```

The request is sent every 500 ms. The app is working fine when there are less users. When the no of users increased to 400 it is sending 502 error for some time then again it starts receiving response. It happens in a loop.

```
GET example.com/oddsApi/getSession/30189407 502
(anonymous) @ 2.e2450141.chunk.js:2
e.exports @ 2.e2450141.chunk.js:2
e.exports @ 2.e2450141.chunk.js:2
Promise.then (async)
s.request @ 2.e2450141.chunk.js:2
r.forEach.s.<computed> @ 2.e2450141.chunk.js:2
(anonymous) @ 2.e2450141.chunk.js:2
value @ main.7f6055f1.chunk.js:1
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ main.7f6055f1.chunk.js:1
Promise.catch (async)
value @ main.7f6055f1.chunk.js:1
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ main.7f6055f1.chunk.js:1
Promise.catch (async)
value @ main.7f6055f1.chunk.js:1
main.7f6055f1.chunk.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at main.7f6055f1.chunk.js:1
```

When i logged this error on the server it is printing:

```
 { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 178.62.105.201:80
0|app  |     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1107:14)
0|app  |   errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
0|app  |   code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
0|app  |   syscall: 'connect',
0|app  |   address: '178.62.105.201',
0|app  |   port: 80,
0|app  |   config:
0|app  |    { url:
0|app  |       'http://178.62.105.201/api/v1/listMarketBookSession?match_id=30189407',
0|app  |      method: 'get',
0|app  |      headers:
0|app  |       { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
0|app  |         'User-Agent': 'axios/0.20.0' },
0|app  |      transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
0|app  |      transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
0|app  |      timeout: 0,
0|app  |      adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
0|app  |      xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
0|app  |      xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
0|app  |      maxContentLength: -1,
0|app  |      maxBodyLength: -1,
0|app  |      validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
0|app  |      data: undefined },
0|app  |   request:
0|app  |    Writable {
0|app  |      _writableState:
0|app  |       WritableState {
0|app  |         objectMode: false,
0|app  |         highWaterMark: 16384,
0|app  |         finalCalled: false,
0|app  |         needDrain: false,
0|app  |         ending: false,
0|app  |         ended: false,
0|app  |         finished: false,
0|app  |         destroyed: false,
0|app  |         decodeStrings: true,
0|app  |         defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
0|app  |         length: 0,
0|app  |         writing: false,
0|app  |         corked: 0,
0|app  |         sync: true,
0|app  |         bufferProcessing: false,
0|app  |         onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
0|app  |         writecb: null,
0|app  |         writelen: 0,
0|app  |         bufferedRequest: null,
0|app  |         lastBufferedRequest: null,
0|app  |         pendingcb: 0,
0|app  |         prefinished: false,
0|app  |         errorEmitted: false,
0|app  |         emitClose: true,
0|app  |         autoDestroy: false,
0|app  |         bufferedRequestCount: 0,
0|app  |         corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
0|app  |      writable: true,
0|app  |      _events:
0|app  |       [Object: null prototype] {
0|app  |         response: [Function: handleResponse],
0|app  |         error: [Function: handleRequestError] },
0|app  |      _eventsCount: 2,
0|app  |      _maxListeners: undefined,
0|app  |      _options:
0|app  |       { maxRedirects: 21,
0|app  |         maxBodyLength: 10485760,
0|app  |         protocol: 'http:',
0|app  |         path: '/api/v1/listMarketBookSession?match_id=30189407',
0|app  |         method: 'GET',
0|app  |         headers: [Object],
0|app  |         agent: undefined,
0|app  |         agents: [Object],
0|app  |         auth: undefined,
0|app  |         hostname: '178.62.105.201',
0|app  |         port: null,
0|app  |         nativeProtocols: [Object],
0|app  |         pathname: '/api/v1/listMarketBookSession',
0|app  |         search: '?match_id=30189407' },
0|app  |      _ended: true,
0|app  |      _ending: true,
0|app  |      _redirectCount: 0,
0|app  |      _redirects: [],
0|app  |      _requestBodyLength: 0,
0|app  |      _requestBodyBuffers: [],
0|app  |      _onNativeResponse: [Function],
0|app  |      _currentRequest:
0|app  |       ClientRequest {
0|app  |         _events: [Object],
0|app  |         _eventsCount: 7,
0|app  |         _maxListeners: undefined,
0|app  |         output: [],
0|app  |         outputEncodings: [],
0|app  |         outputCallbacks: [],
0|app  |         outputSize: 0,
0|app  |         writable: true,
0|app  |         _last: true,
0|app  |         chunkedEncoding: false,
0|app  |         shouldKeepAlive: false,
0|app  |         useChunkedEncodingByDefault: false,
0|app  |         sendDate: false,
0|app  |         _removedConnection: false,
0|app  |         _removedContLen: false,
0|app  |         _removedTE: false,
0|app  |         _contentLength: 0,
0|app  |         _hasBody: true,
0|app  |         _trailer: '',
0|app  |         finished: true,
0|app  |         _headerSent: true,
0|app  |         socket: [Socket],
0|app  |         connection: [Socket],
0|app  |         _header:
0|app  |          'GET /api/v1/listMarketBookSession?match_id=30189407 HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.20.0\r\nHost: 178.62.105.201\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
0|app  |         _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
0|app  |         agent: [Agent],
0|app  |         socketPath: undefined,
0|app  |         timeout: undefined,
0|app  |         method: 'GET',
0|app  |         insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
0|app  |         path: '/api/v1/listMarketBookSession?match_id=30189407',
0|app  |         _ended: false,
0|app  |         res: null,
0|app  |         aborted: undefined,
0|app  |         timeoutCb: null,
0|app  |         upgradeOrConnect: false,
0|app  |         parser: null,
0|app  |         maxHeadersCount: null,
0|app  |         _redirectable: [Circular],
0|app  |         [Symbol(isCorked)]: false,
0|app  |         [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
0|app  |      _currentUrl:
0|app  |       'http://178.62.105.201/api/v1/listMarketBookSession?match_id=30189407' },
0|app  |   response: undefined,
0|app  |   isAxiosError: true,
0|app  |   toJSON: [Function: toJSON] }
```

The code for calling odds:-

```
getOdds() {

        axios.get('/getSession/' + this.props.eventId)
            .then(response => {

                if (response && response.data.data.length && response.data.data[0] !== "\n") {

                    response.data.data.sort((a,b)=>a.SelectionId-b.SelectionId)

                    this.setState({ sessions: response.data.data });
                    if (this.flag)
                        this.intervalID = setTimeout(this.getOdds.bind(this), 300);
                }
                else if (!response.data.data.length) {
                    this.setState({ sessions: null });
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                if (this.flag)
                    this.intervalID = setTimeout(this.getOdds.bind(this), 500);
                console.log(error);
            })
    }
```

which is called on componentDidMount

```
   componentDidMount() {
        this.getOdds();
    }
```

I also tried to log the duration of response. The time duration was variable. Following are some responses

```
Market.js:80 1752
Market.js:80 390
Market.js:80 310
Market.js:80 722
Market.js:80 16002
Market.js:80 15326
Market.js:80 330
Market.js:80 1758
Market.js:80 1144
Market.js:80 308
Market.js:80 709
Market.js:80 324
Market.js:80 351
Market.js:80 647
Market.js:80 375
Market.js:80 406
Market.js:80 701
Market.js:80 345
Market.js:80 1776
Market.js:80 1187
Market.js:80 414
Market.js:80 715
Market.js:80 20327
```

As u can see sometimes it is taking around 20s to give response, which is giving me nightmare. When I contacted the third party API provider, they told me their API can handle more than 20000 users. I am not able debug the issue. Maybe I have not prepared my app well for scaling. Please Help!

Comment: Can you show us how do you call the ```getOdds``` function?

Comment: It would be helpful to see a performance scale or chart of your server if it's hit the 400 users. I am not a server admin but I assume if till 400 users running everything proper and from 400 no more it could be a performance issue. Of course it should be intercept somewhere in your request code then.

Comment: getOdds is called in componentDidMount

Comment: Check whether your sql query runs `count(*)`. If so, it could be the culprit.

Comment: i am not able to understand your solution @t348575

Comment: often in large tables with multiple primary keys and indexes `count(*)` can take sometimes 20, 30 (seconds) or more to run

Comment: But to call the odds there is no sql query involved on my side, i am just calling the third party api for the odds

Comment: maybe your third party API has a request rate limit? also why don't you call the third party api directly from your frontend instead of through your server

Comment: i can't call it directly because they have to track my server static ip

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS; 
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
AND Optional, if available - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.